# Make a 2 way sharing folder with my PC

Tags: windows, sharing, file-sharing, network

I've been trying to make a sharing folder with my PC for so long and it seems to complicated. In windows 7 there is Homesharing and the configuration is so easy.

I would like to make a folder which will work both ways (Windows input will appear in mac and mac input will pop out in windows)

Is there a way to do this? I have tried the `System Preferences` -> `Sharing` -> `Files Sharing` option but it does not seem to get connected to my windows, it says the connection could not be established.

Please help me get over this frustrating compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem

Mac was not connecting to PC because "for a reason I don't know" , my PC's account **had** to have a password.

I create a password for my account and Now I can share folders with my mac.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder is shared from Windows and is accessible from other Windows machines then it should be accessible from your Mac as well. There are two possible causes to the problem you are describing:

1. You are using OS X 10.8.0 and you are trying to connect to `smb://<machine>` instead of `smb://<machine>/<share>`. If this is the case then the solution is to connect to `smb://<machine>/<share>`.
2. You are using any version of OS X and you are trying to connect to `smb://<machine>/<share>`. If this is the case then you probably aren't entering the username correctly. On your Mac when connecting to a Windows file share you should try entering the username as `WORKGROUP\<username>`. (Case may matter)

NOTE: I got into the habit of always entering the username in that format way back in OS X 10.3 (maybe even earlier.) It could be that it is no longer required, but it has never failed me, so I just stick with what works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Install iTunes on PC (if its not installed already, if its a VERY old version update it) ... this will get you the Bonjour service installed and running on it.
- Open explorer and go to the folder you wish to share, press right click -> properties -> Sharing Tab -> Advanced Share
- Check the "Share this folder" checkmark
- Fill a descriptive name in Share (ie: HD Movies, or Family Pics ..)
- Optional: Click Permissions and choose if shared access is R/W or R only. In most cases use R/W unless you are afraid of accidental deletion.

Join the same network and the windows machine should pop up in the Mac's Finder. If it doesnt try to force a connection press Command+K and write the name of the PC.